# Get the class structure instance of a GObject type

Tags: gtk, gobject

How do I get a *class object* of a certain class in GObject / Gtk? For example, if my class is GtkSpinButton, I want to get the instance of GtkSpinButtonClass that represents the class. It is the parameter "class" in

```
gtk_spin_button_class_init (GtkSpinButtonClass *class)
```

and it is the object where virtual functions are stored. When I have an instance of GtkSpinButton, I can call

```
GtkSpinButtonClass *class = GTK_SPIN_BUTTON_GET_CLASS (instance)
```

however I don't have an instance around. `GTK_TYPE_SPIN_BUTTON` gives me the type id, a number, and not the class object. Any idea how to get the actual instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `g_type_class_ref`

```
GtkSpinButtonClass *klass = g_type_class_ref(GTK_TYPE_SPIN_BUTTON);
```

and when you're done with it

```
g_type_class_unref(klass);
```

Comment: Note that (A) `g_type_class_ref()` creates the class if needed, i.e. if no one else already did, and (B) there is `g_type_class_peek()` that avoids the need to create/ref/unref if you are sure the class already exists (or are happy to check for `NULL`) and do not need to hold a reference. See the full details at [the relevant area of the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#g-type-class-ref).